# Unable to get the deployed contract address using etherjs

Tags: hardhat, ether, web3-react

I am trying to deploy my contract and get the address of deployed contract but is shows

"undefined".
Here is the code of deploy.js:

```
//deploy.js

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

  console.log(
    "Account balance:",
    await deployer.provider.getBalance(deployer.address)
  );

  const chai = await ethers.getContractFactory("chai");
  const chaiContract = await chai.deploy();
  await chaiContract.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("Deployed address:" + chaiContract.address);
}
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

The version of ether.js i am using is 5.7.1

[.json screenshot of dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuj5p.png)

The output i am getting after deployment is :

```
Deploying contracts with the account: 0x5A5171B2353f0A6Fd735e1564a96790d26465860
```

```
Account balance: 606092519791070461n
```

```
Deployed address:undefined
```

I was expecting the ouput to display the address to which my contract is deployed  but whatever i am trying it still says "undefined". and the soldiity file name of my project is chai.sol . i even tried to replace chaiContract.address to chai.address but the result is same.
Can anyone please help me fix this problem.

Comment: The screenshot shows `ethers` used by `@nomicfoundation/ethereumjs-block` and not the version you installed.

Comment: To get your `ethers` version, type: `npm ls ethers`

Comment: The version is v6 . i haved checked it

Comment: Can you do `console.log(chaiContract)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using chaiContract.target instead of chaiContract.address